# How to use CSS3 and make an element be transparent to its parent's parent overlaying another element?

Tags: html, css

Ugh this is difficult to articulate. Best explained by looking at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLKdk/5/

So here the problem is, the wood texture is broken because the child element is using background: inherit which starts the background all over again. Is there any way to achieve this?

Markup:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"> </div>
  <div class="div3"> </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.div1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;    
    background: url(http://blog.webair.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/wood-texture-1.jpg);
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: 175px;
    left: 125px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Background-position fixed would do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think radial-gradient might be a better solution in the long run. It's more semantic and doesn't require junk markup for cosmetic effect.

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle 25px at 50% 100%, transparent 25px, lightyellow 25px);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100%, circle, transparent 25px, lightyellow 25px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AcA9k/1/

Comment: To make sure that webkitbased browsers use the up-to-date syntax, set first the prefixed one and last the unprefixed. Anyway, +1, it's better than the other way suggested

Answer (score 3):

you can fix this , using `background-attachement:fixed` on both containers laying the wood texture.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLKdk/6/)**

*Here i used the shorthand writing: `background: url(http://blog.webair.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/wood-texture-1.jpg) fixed;`*

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to div3 you should be able to reposition the background to the desired position. I haven't actually worked out what the values are so they won't look right when you put these values in but you should be able to change them to get the desired effect.

```
.div3 {
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: 125px 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you been trying to make the BG look correct in the round area?

quickest fix (for unchanging positions) is to use background-position ...
not the best solution for resizing areas thought.

added to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLKdk/10/)
 using `background-position: -111px -167px;`